# Add a reference to the System.IdentityModel.Tokens DLL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

How do I add a reference to the System.IdentityModel.Tokens dll?

It does not seem to come up in the Nuget Package Manager.

Do I need to download the DLL?

I have .Net 4.5 installed.

The following code will not compile without the reference:

```
SessionSecurityToken sst = e.SessionToken;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does exist on NuGet, and was last published 2013-02-08, so I don't understand why you couldn't find it. Try searching for *System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry*.
The best way is to install it is using the NuGet packet manager.

You can find the package here: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry/4.5.0

Comment: You are right. It does exist and it comes up now simply by typing "system.identitymodel.tokens". I am not sure why it did not come up before either.

Answer (score 5):

In your solution, right click the References folder and choose "Add Reference"

From the Assemblies->Framework (.NET 4.5) list, select (check) `System.IdentityModel` and the press ok.

Add the using statement to the top of your class - `using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;`

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone else.

Depending on what class you need you may also need reference to

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry.dll
```

This may not be obvious as it may be implicitly required by specific element in web.config file and not explicitly required in code.